# How to generate API docs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

How can I generate docs in a nice format such as:
https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/body/#log-body-fat
https://jawbone.com/up/developer/endpoints/moves

Is there a service that can help with this task? I'm using `asp.net MVC` and `WebApi`

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can by running this command from package manager console.

Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage

For more detail see:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages

Rest UI part you can improve.

Comment: Yes, but this creates default styling. Are there any theming / templates for webapi help pages?

Comment: Its on you to custmize the default styling or choose a theme and impliment it, by default it is using bootstrap.